# Expected max load with $m$ balls into $n$ bins

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

Suppose that we randomly drop *n<sup>3/2</sup>* balls into *n* bins. Give an upper bound on the expectation of the maximum number of balls in any bin.

I have seen somewhat similar questions but no good answer for this kind of problem. First, we know that the expected number of balls in any bin is *n<sup>1/2</sup>*. Then, I think we need to use Chernoff bounds but that's the part I am struggling with. Usually, we have to set a δ but I don't know equal to what.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let $Y$ be the maximum number of balls in any bin. Chernoff like arguments give you $P(Y \ge k) \le f(k)$ for some $f$. Since $Y\ge 0$ surely, you can now use $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \sum_{k \ge 1} P(Y \ge k) \le \sum_{k\ge 1} f(k)$ for an upper bound on the expectation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I follow what you are doing. My question is how do we find that *f(k)* ? @stochasticboy321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the # of balls in the $i$th bin and $X = \max\{X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n\}$. We have
$$
\mathsf{E}(X) = \sum_{i \geq 1} \Pr(X \geq i) \leq \sum_{i > 2n^{1/2} + 9\ln n} \Pr(X \geq i) + 2n^{1/2} + 9\ln n
$$
and for $i > 2n^{1/2} + 9\ln n$, 
\begin{align}
\Pr(X \geq i) &= \Pr(X_1 \geq i\ \lor\ X_2 \geq i\ \lor\ \cdots\ \lor\ X_n \geq i) \\
&\leq \sum_{j = 1}^n \Pr(X_j \geq i) \\
&\leq \sum_{j=1}^n \mathsf{exp}\left( - \frac{i - n^{1/2}}{3}\right) \\
&\leq \sum_{j=1}^n \mathsf{exp}\left(-3\ln n\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}
\end{align}
where

- $X_j \sim \mathsf{Binomial}~(n^{3/2}, \frac{1}{n})$ and $\mathsf{E}(X_j) = \sqrt{n}$;
- the first inequality uses the union bound;
- the second inequality uses a loose form of [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_.28relative_error.29):
  $$
  \Pr(X \geq (1 + \delta)\mu) \leq \mathsf{exp}(-\frac{\delta\mu}{3}) \quad\text{for}\ \delta > 1
  $$
  Therefore,
  $$
  \sum_{i > 2n^{1/2} + 9\ln n} \Pr(X \geq i) \leq n^{3/2} \cdot \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
  $$
  implying an upper bound
  $$
  \mathsf{E}(X) \leq 2\sqrt{n} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + 9 \ln n
  $$

Comment: Very neat thank you !

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand where $2n^{1/2}+9 ln n$ comes from

Comment: @Rob It is a value selected such that when we apply the Chernoff bound, the formula would not be too tedious.